# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' error

Tags: php, mysql

heyy guys....

i know this is probably a silly error but i really tried hard to solve this error, but can't seem to find the cause...

```
    $id=$_GET['uid'];
    $name=$_GET['uname'];
    $empnum=$_GET['empnum'];
    $status=$_GET['status'];
    $role=$_GET['role'];

    //--SQL query : Fetching data from main_data and how many data row exists
    $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE UserID='$id'");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($sql1);

    if($count>0)
    {
        echo "User ID exists";
        header("refresh:1;url=newregistration.php" );
    }
    else
    {
        //sql commands to insert the data into the database
        sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET UserID='$id' WHERE UserID='$id'";        //sql query defined
        sql2="UPDATE $tbl_name SET UserName='$name' WHERE UserID='$id'";
        sql3="UPDATE $tbl_name SET EmpNumber='$empnum' WHERE UserID='$id'";
        sql4="UPDATE $tbl_name SET Status='$status' WHERE UserID='$id'";
        sql5="UPDATE $tbl_name SET Role='$role' WHERE UserID='$id'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql1) or mysql_error(); 
        $result=mysql_query($sql2) or mysql_error();
        $result=mysql_query($sql3) or mysql_error();
        $result=mysql_query($sql4) or mysql_error();
        $result=mysql_query($sql5) or mysql_error();
```

would be grateful if someone can point out my mistake...

thank you

-- Update --

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\ReportTrackingSystem\updateregistration.php on line 43 $sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET UserID='$id' WHERE UserID='$id'";
```

Comment: Where does it say the error is? What line?

Comment: Get an editor with syntax highlighting, or an IDE with code linting. Also post syntax problems in the chat or somewhere, not as question.

Comment: try echoing the values of id and other variable

Comment: Variable need `$` before it. (sql1,sql2...)

Comment: Why are you not combining the update into 1 query? and also you have sql injections & undefined variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to go off of without an exact error message, but these (sql1, sql2, etc) should be variables (flagged with $):

```
$sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET UserID='$id' WHERE UserID='$id'";        //sql query defined
$sql2="UPDATE $tbl_name SET UserName='$name' WHERE UserID='$id'";
$sql3="UPDATE $tbl_name SET EmpNumber='$empnum' WHERE UserID='$id'";
$sql4="UPDATE $tbl_name SET Status='$status' WHERE UserID='$id'";
$sql5="UPDATE $tbl_name SET Role='$role' WHERE UserID='$id'";
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\ReportTrackingSystem\updateregistration.php on line 43
$sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET UserID='$id' WHERE UserID='$id'";

Comment: The code as written looks correct, check the value of `$tbl_name` and `$id` to make sure they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: The comment you posted is correct, the code you posted in your original question is not. You need to prefix the `sql1, sql2, ...` with `$` as I stated in answer.

Comment: Why are you not recommending to the OP to update in 1 query/use prepared querys or close the injections & clear up the Notice: Undefined errors, just because something is fixed, is not something necessarily thats right.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: Feel free to add your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

you forget to put `$` before variables
`$sq1` etc.,